# Access deep link in android

Tags: android, google-app-indexing

I am investigating about Google indexing on android
( developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction )

I have tried to demo like that:

- When click on deep link ( dantri.com.vn ) -> open on app
- When click on deep link ( dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/  -> just open on browser
  but still can't solve it.
  Some experienced engineer can solve this problem? please help me. thank you so much.

Comment: What is your manifest conf for that?

Comment: This is my config <data android:scheme="http" android:host="dantri.com.vn" android:pathPattern=".*\\/.*\\/" /> –

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is on your AndroidManifest.xml.

The 'pathPattern' must start with a '/', so the correct way of doing it would be:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="dantri.com.vn" android:pathPattern="\\/.*\\/.*\\/" />
```

You have more information about the AndroidManifest.xml in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path).